# Record audio data to an existing media file using FFMPEG API

Tags: c++, encoding, ffmpeg

My task is to record the received audio data in a media file. I have no problem with this, everything works fine. But, when closing the audio file, I will no longer be able to re-open it and write the audio data to the end of the audio file. How do I solve this problem ?  And in general, is it possible to write new data to the end of an existing media file ?

This is a piece of code where I record the trailer and close the media file:

```cpp
// Writing the stream trailer to an output
// media file and free the file private data.
av_write_trailer(p_oFrmCtx);
avformat_close_input(&p_oFrmCtx);
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, opening an existing audio file and writing to it is not possible. What you can do is write the incoming data to a new file and merge it with the previous one (the one at the end of which you wanted to write the data). You can use below command to achieve that.

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3" -acodec copy output.mp3
```

If you have a list of files to be merged together, run the below command

```
$ ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i filelist.txt -c copy output.mp3
```

Note the list should be of following format

```
$ cat filelist.txt
file '/audio/001.mp3'
file '/audio/002.mp3'
file '/audio/003.mp3'
file '/audio/004.mp3'
```